# What does "like being drowned in Skittles" mean?

Tags: meaning, expressions

From here: http://www.loper-os.org/?p=568

> Using Squeak is “like being drowned in Skittles.” I understand that it is a monumentally great thing if one is able to see past that, but I suspect that most prospective users cannot do so.

I searched for an explanation, but I can't seem to find one. Does it mean that you're getting "too much" good stuff? So much that it's actually a disadvantage?

Comment: That commenter probably read [this](http://www.adweek.com/adfreak/british-man-verge-drowning-skittles-12062).  The phrase gets only 9 hits on google.

Comment: It's just a reference to [Skittles vodka](http://mixthatdrink.com/skittles-vodka-tutorial/). There's no such "idiom" - it's a one-off jokey comparison.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: eh? Where the heck do you get a *vodka* reference out of this? (If you meant that as a joke, a smiley would be helpful.)

Comment: @Marthaª: I got it by typing the word "skittles" in to google, and noting that the top choice in google instant was to auto-complete it as **skittles vodka**. I first posted my comment assuming that was a brand name, but before my 5 minute "edit comments grace period" was up, I'd gone to look at an actual page and discovered **Skittles** are American sweeties that people currently like to dissolve in vodka. Which is probably all I want to know about them! :)

Comment: ...I take it that since the number of votes to close is still **one** (mine), you don't believe my theory. I'm sure there won't be an interesting backstory to this one!

Comment: @FumbleFingers, that's like finding a reference to a cult of people who, I dunno, like to plant golf clubs in their gardens, and thereafter defining *golf club* as "a lawn ornament".

Comment: @Marthaª: I don't follow. My position is this question is far too localised, so I posted the "answer" as a comment and voted to close. I don't think ELU is enhanced by having lots of people post actual Answers and upvote each other on one-off trivia like this.

Comment: I don't think it's that localised - Skittles are kind of like Smarties (only they don't taste so nice) and they are known the world over for their bright colours

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I'm saying this phrase has absolutely nothing to do with vodka, and you dragging a weird cordial into the question is, um, perplexing. To say the least. (Also, if you don't know what Skittles are, then you probably don't have enough information to determine whether this question is too localized or not, so you should probably refrain from voting on it. Just saying.)

Comment: ...OP isn't asking for a definition of "skittles" (which to me would have nothing to do with sweeties anyway). He wanted to know why someone would talk about "drowning in Skittles". But note that *he* capitalised it, as did the original writer, so that should have been a clue to anyone (even Brits, who wouldn't know the brand-name or type of product).

Comment: I don't believe this! Google "I drink skittles", or "skittles vodka", then tell me this isn't about a cocktail which is regarded as exceptionally luscious!

Comment: @FumbleFingers, ok, you and I are really in different universes or something. Why is the capitalization suddenly an issue? Skittles is a brand name, it ought to be capitalized. And nobody accused the OP of asking for a definition of *Skittles*. I'm accusing you and your vodka reference of being about as relevant as lawn ornaments are to golf clubs, i.e. not at all.

Comment: @Rory Alsop: Note Daniel's comment above. **Nine** hits for *drowned in skittles*, and they led him to something irrelevant anyway. This is a one-off expression used by someone who plainly likes his Skittles "cocktail" and assumes others on the forum will know what he means. The rest of the world is not going to start using this as a set phrase, because it is *highly localised*.

Comment: @Martha: There is no arguing with you. I'm more or less certain I have identified why that forum poster used the expression. If you think I'm wrong, I leave it to you to find a more plausible explanation for his turn of phrase.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - no, it is a phrase which I wouldn't even need to google to know what it means. We have skittles here in the UK. They are colourful. Look  at the Squeak application. It's pretty self explanatory. There is no connection with some cocktail which no-one has heard of outside the US.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Rory Alsop has already found a more plausible explanation (at least, if you know anything at all about Squeak).

Comment: ...if it's still not clear, the writer either means using Squeak is exceptionally *nice* (unlikely), or he means it's very *confusing* (as would be drowning in vodka, mixed with sweeties or not).

Comment: @FumbleFingers: it's much more literal. Using Squeak is exceptionally *colorful*. And the colors are all very vibrant and candy-like. Like drowning in Skittles.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Skittles are pretty well known in Britain. I could sing you an ad jingle from the 1980s (but won't)

Comment: Just to add my (British) viewpoint. The Skittles, "rainbow of fruit flavours" ad was on TV ad nausium in the late 80s early 90s (and I believe the sweets are still available as far as I know). Surely the reference is to bright colours rather than a fad of disolving such sweets in vodka. The problem with Google referencing (and the auto-complete) is that the new often overwhelms the long-standing common association. If I googled "Balotelli" today, I might get the impression it was the name of a rare and unusual stamp!

Comment: I can't hear 'skittles' without thinking 'Tom Leher'.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: "[Skittles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skittles_(confectionery)#History_and_overview) were first made commercially in 1974 by a British company.[3] They were first introduced in North America in 1979 as an import confectionery.[4] In 1982, domestic production of Skittles
began in the United States. Skittles' "taste the rainbow" theme was
created by New York ad agency D'Arcy Masius Benton & Bowles circa 1994.[5]"

Comment: [Drowning in Skittles](http://wiki.squeak.org/squeak/uploads/morphic_squeak.gif), [drowning in Squeak](http://www.contagiousmagazine.com/magazine/Skittles1.jpg)

Comment: @Hugo possibly you have the links transposed

Answer (score 7):

It's just a reference to the overdone colour scheme on [Squeak](http://squeak.org/):

> Skittles come in all rainbow colours.

Comment: It's still a hopelessly localised question and didn't deserve a formal answer!

Comment: Why are you so grumpy, FumbleFingers? I couldn't have known that it wasn't a real expression, I thought it might just have been misspelled or something. I never encountered Skittles in my life. I read the FAQ and I don't think I broke any rules. Just how informal must an answer to a question like mine be? Judging from the discussion above, you didn't even get the meaning yourself, so just be thankful that it was explained to you. Anyway, I'm sad the comment was so childish -- Squeak isn't that colorful, and Pharo isn't popular, even with the Mac like color scheme.

Comment: @user309483: I'm not grumpy at you for asking the question. Okay, maybe the reference is to the colour of "Skittles" rather than the fact that there's a fad for mixing them in vodka. But your writer's usage isn't meaningfully an "English expression" - it's a highly localised cultural issue, so all we needed here was for you to get an answer in a comment, then close it. No-one else is likely to come here because they've just heard it and don't understand - it might well never be said again!

Comment: ...also note that even if the guy had said "It's like swimming in treacle" I'd have wanted to close after a comment. It's not my fault I'm not American so I never heard of Skittles, but these are (or should be) transparent usages for the people they're aimed at.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I don't mind closing localized questions, but I also don't think "too localized" (even "hopelessly" localized) somehow makes a question undeserving of an answer. Particularly with idiomatic usages, sometimes there's no way to tell something is so localized unless you ask first. Yoichi asks many questions that end up too localized, but there's no way to tell that from the outset, and I wouldn't chastise anyone for providing an answer – even in those instances where closure is the question's ultimate destiny and proper fate.

Comment: @J.R.: The way I look at it is: if a publishing house decided to create a (say) 100-volume edition of idiomatic/unusual expressions you wouldn't find in the average dictionary, would they bother to include whatever the OP is asking about? If I think "probably not", I consider the question Too Localised. OP should still get an "answer" via comments (which imho he has, here), but where's the sense in doling out 14 (current tally) rep points for people posting actual Answers?

Answer (score 7):

Being drowned in Skittles refers specifically to *the television commercials for the Skittles candy*. In the commercials, millions of Skittles invariably end up falling out of the sky like a heavy rain. Being drowned in Skittles, then, is a metaphor. It means being knocked down and overcome by a deluge of colorful things.